# Will libraries loaded with LD_PRELOAD be unload in the last

Tags: linux, linker, ld-preload

I am writing a memory leak tracker, and want to print the statistics messages in the tracked program at the time the library unloading.

This library will be used with the `LD_PRELOAD` trick, our programs have static variables that will be destroyed very late, so I want to be assured that the statistics messages will be printed after all the static variables in the program have been destroyed to avoid false alarm.

Will libraries loaded with LD_PRELOAD be unload in the last (Later than the hacked programs)?

Comment: I don't think it's deterministic.  Q: have you considered LD_DEBUG?

Comment: Glad to know `LD_DEBUG`， thanks, I will take a look

Comment: @paulsm4 I have checked the doc for LD_DEBUG, but I haven't find the option for printing unloading library log, could you please check it?

Comment: Q: Do you mean that LD_DEBUG doesn't show it (I believe it does, but I'm not 100% sure)?  Or do you mean that you want to "capture" LD_DEBUG output (e.g. to a disk file), so you can print it later?  If the latter, look at [script](https://linux.die.net/man/1/script), [tee](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tee) or simply use I/O redirection (e.g. `2>&1`).

Comment: @paulsm4 I have checked the doc and have a try, we can add an option such as `LD_DEBUG=bindings,symbols`, but it seems that we don't have an option to print the library unloading log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will libraries loaded with LD_PRELOAD be unload in the last

You are assuming that `LD_PRELOADED` library will be unloaded, but there is no guarantee that this will happen at all.

Here is a test case:

```
// main.c
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc > 1) _exit(0);
  return 0;
}

// preload.c
#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__((constructor)) void init() { fprintf(stderr, "Init\n"); }
__attribute__((destructor)) void fini() { fprintf(stderr, "Fini\n"); }
```

Build them like so:

```
gcc main.c && gcc -fPIC -shared -o preload.so preload.c
```

Now observe the order of initialization and finalization:

```
LD_DEBUG=files LD_PRELOAD=./preload.so ./a.out |& grep 'calling .*ini'
     18310:     calling init: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
     18310:     calling init: ./preload.so
     18310:     calling fini: ./a.out [0]
     18310:     calling fini: ./preload.so [0]

LD_DEBUG=files LD_PRELOAD=./preload.so ./a.out 1 |& grep 'calling .*ini'
     18312:     calling init: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
     18312:     calling init: ./preload.so
```

Notice that in the case of `_exit()` the library is not finalized at all.

Also notice that *any* shared library will have a dependency on `libc.so.6`, and thus will be finalized *before* `libc.so.6`.

But absent signal or `_exit()` termination, yes: the libraries will be finalized in reverse order of their initialization (loading and unloading aren't really the right terms to use here), and that does mean that `LD_PRELOAD`ed libraries will be finalized last.

Comment: Thanks so much, it there any deterministic unload sequence? From your answer, I learned that without calling APIs like `_exit` the unloading will happen, and finalized before `libc.so.6` and some other libraries like `ld.so` is also acceptable. Though some leak will be found in ld.so.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin I've updated the answer. Yes, there is an order.